# What is this game with a dark alleyway and a red neon sign reading 'Terminus'?

Tags: game-identification

[image: Screenshot from video about a game]

I got this picture from a random video about games. I think it is a PC game, but I have no idea about its name.

Comment: Could you link the video you got this from for more context

Answer (score 51, accepted):

It's from [Hitman Absolution.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hitman:_Absolution)

Videos/Articles showing the scene:

- http://www.games73.com/1/2014/03/17/4k-screenshot-showcase-hitman-absolution/

Comment: I was just about to guess Hitman Absolution before seeing your answer, loved that game!